# regex email with angled brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

So I am trying to validate a string with contains first some text, then an email surrounded by angled brackets '<>', for example

`'Test <postmaster@email.academy>'`

I have been trying to solve this for quite some time, I want to know if there is a regex that will help me to validate that the email is always surrounded by angled brackets

```
var data = {
    from: 'Test <postmaster@email.com>',
};

var dataValidation = function (data){
    var fromEmailAddress = data.from.split(' '); //['Test','<postmaster@email.com>']
    /////code below doesn't work as I have angled brackets around the email
    var validEmail = /^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+.)+([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum)$/;
    if(validEmail.test(fromEmailAddress[1])){
        console.log(fromEmailAddress[1])
    }

};
```

Comment: So why not add these angle brackets to the regex? `/^<[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+.)+([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum)>$/.test("<postmaster@email.com>")`. Or even `/^<[\w.%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+.)+([A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum)>$/.test("<postmaster@email.com>")`

Comment: also, if you will have problems with regs in further this is a very helpful service http://regexr.com/

Comment: "([a-zA-z ]+)(<(?:([a-zA-z._%+-]+)@([a-zA-z]+)\\.([a-zA-z]{3,4}|museum))>)" try this

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}|museum` is really poor for matching TLD's, see: http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db

Comment: @Toto — I'm amused at the special casing for museum while ignoring all the others.

Comment: Or http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt